# specify IP address in salt cloud

Tags: salt-cloud

If I have a specific private IP address in mind for an ec2 instance, how can I specify it in a salt cloud profile

```
ec2_private_win_app1:
  provider: company-nonpod-us-east-1
  image: ami-xxxxxxxx
  size: c4.large
  network_interfaces:
   - DeviceIndex: 0
     SubnetId: subnet-xxxxxxxx
     SecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxxxx
  PrivateIpAddresses:
   - Primary: True
  #auto assign public ip (not EIP)
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: False
  tag: {'Engagement': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Owner': 'Tim', 'Name': 'production'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are well.

Your current config is very close.
To specify a private IP in a profile, you'll want to simply add:

```
PrivateIpAddress: 192.168.133.105
```

Or w/e address you wish it to be assigned.  Note that you'll need this AS WELL AS

```
PrivateIpAddresses:
  - primary: True
```

Comment: If I try adding the IP the way you suggest, it breaks the yaml and salt-cloud gives a python stack trace. If I define the ip address this way: `PrivateIpAddresses: 
         - Primary: True
   - ip: 10.48.128.45` the yaml works. But the ec2 instances has an autoassigned IP. How can I specify this correctly>

Comment: Hm, interesting.  So you have autoassign IPs turned on in EC2, for that subnet?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: is it possible to test it by temporarily turning them off? It might be the case that the autoassign is overriding the network adapter specification.